# NodeJS/Express MongoDB toArray() doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get all documents into array so i can use array.forEach to do something with each document. I'm not into using stream.

according to mongodb official documentation, find() should return a cursor:

> Consider the following example that applies toArray() to the cursor returned from the find() method:

```
    var allProductsArray = db.products.find().toArray(); 
if (allProductsArray.length > 0) { printjson (allProductsArray[0]); }
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

My current codebase:

```
            //success, get and list apps in json
            var userId = new ObjectId(resultUser._id);
            var appRes = capidb.collection("api_applications").find({application_owner: userId}).toArray()
            if (appRes) {
                console.log("UserID: " + userId + " | : "+appRes.length)
                res.send("ae")
                //appRes.forEach(function(appRes) {
                    //console.log(appRes.application_name)
                //})
            } else {
                res.status(204)
                .json({success: false, code: "NoContent", message: "There wasn't any applications to list."}) 
            }
```

doesn't work as properly. The `console.log("UserID: " + userId + " | : "+appRes.length)`
outputs: `UserID: <the userId> | : undefined`

`<the userId>` works properly, just masked out the actuall userId of mine.

So the .length returns "undefined", and why is that?

UPDATE:
I also tried this documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/#find-all-documents

making an async function:

```
const findApplications = async function(userid) {
    const appRes = await capidb.collection("api_applications").find({application_owner: userid}).toArray();
    return appRes;
}
```

and initiating it:

```
            //success, get and list apps in json
            var userId = new ObjectId(resultUser._id);
            const appRes = findApplications(userId);

            if (appRes) {
                console.log("UserID: " + userId + " | : "+appRes.length)
                res.send("ae")
                //appRes.forEach(function(appRes) {
                    //console.log(appRes.application_name)
                //})
            } else {
                res.status(204)
                .json({success: false, code: "NoContent", message: "There wasn't any applications to list."}) 
            }
```

and that also returns undefined.

ASYNC UPDATE:
I tried to make the router function async, to access the findApplications() function:

```
router.get("/:tat", async function(req, res) {
...
}
```

and i also made the function request await:

```
const appRes = await findApplications(userId);
```

even tho now i get the error:

```
                    const appRes = await findApplications(userId);
                                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: _"This page documents a mongosh method. This is not the documentation for a language-specific driver such as Node.js."_. See [this page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#std-label-node-fundamentals-cursor-array) on how `toArray()` works in Node.js.

Comment: @robertklep yes look on my update, i tried to do an async function.

Comment: `findApplications()` is async, so you need to treat it as such in the code where you call it.

Comment: So i need to have this router.get("/:tat", (req, res) => { } async too? how would i do that? i never dealt with async's before in nodejs.

Comment: `router.get('/:tat', async (req, res) => { … })`

Comment: I did now, and still returns undefined. i made the router.get function async.

Comment: Obviously also `await findApplications()`

Comment: `const appRes = await findApplications(userId);
                                   ^^^^^SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
and i added ` router.get("/:tat", async (req, res) => {}` i did also add function after async, same error

Comment: You're going to have to post more info in your question

Comment: Look at the new update i published.

Comment: I got it to work, found out the problem laid on the other database, that wasn't async. So changed that to async and now the system works as expected. Thanks for participating in a solution.